# Running a docker with aws credential: NoCredentialsError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, streamlit

I have created an python app which is connected to a S3 bucket and it works perfectly in local.

But when I build an image and run the contener, the app is unable to connect to the S3.
I have this error:

```
NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 418, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError()
```

I have copy my aws credential at the root of the docker and inside the folder with all files, but nothing works.

That what looks like my docker file (newbie in docker) :

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
COPY .aws ./.aws
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8501
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run"]
CMD ["page_accueil.py"]
```

The purpose is then to deploy on AWS Fargate.

How can I create a Docker contener and still connect my app to my S3 bucket ?

Many thanks,

Comment: You should not copy credentials into a docker container, rather use the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables when running locally, and let Fargate's metadata server provide the credentials when running in that context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it is normal to be able to run a contener locally, as it can get any access. When I run locally (not in a contener) aws goes straight get the credentials to the folder .aws located at C:\Users\users.